# Read a text file into a pandas dataframe or numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, text, dataframe

I have a file that looks like this - http://pastebin.com/u1A7v1CV

It's just a sample of two rows from a file. 
The rows contain `word_label_id` followed by `freq`. 
For example, `word_label_id` 1237 occurs 1 time in the first row, 1390 occurs 1 time and so on...

I need to use this sparse representation but I'm unable to convert it into a `DataFrame` or any other usable format.

Edit: I know that pandas has a `read_csv` method where I can use a space as the delimiter. This is not ideal as I need two separators - one between `word_label_id` and `freq` and a different separator between this pair and the next.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's not ideal but you can use notepad++.

It had a "find and replace" feature and you can use \t to replace tabs as \n

Then you can record a macro to move any given line to the previous, skipping lines.

Then you can use pandas, pd.from_csv but you have to define delimiters as tabs instead of commas

Another option is to read each line,and process it separately.  Basically a while loop with the condition being not m_line == null

Then inside the loop, split the string up with str.split ()

And have another loop that makes a dictionary, for each row.  In the end, you'd have a list of dictionaries where each entry is ID:frequency

Comment: I need two different delimiters - one between the `word_label_id` and `freq` which can be a space and another between *this* (`word_label_id`, `freq`) combination and the next.

Comment: So recording a macro in notepad ++ might do the trick, but I left this as a wiki answer because I left a lot of details out

Comment: *"... replace tabs as \n"* I just download the file.  It does not contain any tabs.

Comment: Then use the space character or consecutive white space (if you don't know regex then excel might help here)

Comment: Yep, there are no tabs. Only spaces.

Comment: @user2539738  Take a look at the file.  The only separators are single spaces and the line separator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried work separately with each item?

For example:

Open document:

```
with open('delimiters.txt') as r:
    lines = r.readlines()
    linecontent = ' '.join(lines)
```

Create a list for each item:

```
result = linecontent.replace(' ', ',').split(',')
```

Create sublist for ids and freqs:

```
newResult = [result[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(result), 2)]
```

Working with each data type:

```
ids = [x[0][:] for x in newResult]
freq = [x[1][:] for x in newResult]
```

Create a DataFrame

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A ids': ids, 'B freq': freq})
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I did this using `read_csv` and then applied a split method on the column which gives me several columns containing NaN because the length of each row varies.

Comment: `read_csv` with `sep=' '` or even `sep=' \n'` will give *NaN* elements. Working with `readlines()` could avoid those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.
This creates a dictionary containing key-value pairs 
from each row.

```
data = []

with open('../data/input.mat', 'r') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        l = line.split()
        d = dict([(k, v) for k, v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])])
        data.append(d)
```